# Launch S Planner from my ADF Mobile Application

Tags: oracle-maf

I have amx page where I have taken commad button. I want to invoke S Planner application from my MAF Application. Is there any way to invoke it? Plzzz help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for what you need here ( also cross platform - iOS/Android ) can be a Cordova plugin for the calendar. There is a similar question [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3731954?start=0&tstart=0) for this issue, I think it will be useful for you.